# how to save the markers position with jquery to the mysql database

Tags: php, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muviH.png)

---

here is the php code:

---

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropPin/dropPin.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="dropPin/dropPin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#map').dropPin('dropMulti',{
            fixedHeight:413,
            fixedWidth:700,
            cursor: 'crosshair',
            pinclass: 'qtipinfo'
    });

});
</script>
```

---

here is the js code:

---

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.dropPin = function(method) {

        var defaults = {
        fixedHeight: 500,
        fixedWidth: 500,
        dropPinPath: '/js/dropPin/',
        pin: 'dropPin/defaultpin@2x.png',
        backgroundImage: 'dropPin/access-map.png',
        backgroundColor: '#9999CC',
        xoffset : 10,
        yoffset : 30, //need to change this to work out icon heigh/width then subtract margin from it
        cursor: 'crosshair',
        pinclass: '',
        userevent: 'click',
        hiddenXid: '#xcoord', //used for saving to db via hidden form field
        hiddenYid: '#ycoord', //used for saving to db via hidden form field
        pinX: false, //set to value if you pass pin co-ords to overirde click binding to position
        pinY: false, //set to value if you pass pin co-ords to overirde click binding to position
        pinDataSet: '' //array of pin coordinates for front end render
    }



    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var thisObj = this;

            this.css({'cursor' : options.cursor, 'background-color' : options.backgroundColor , 'background-image' : "url('"+options.backgroundImage+"')",'height' : options.fixedHeight , 'width' : options.fixedWidth});
            var i = 10;
            thisObj.on(options.userevent, function (ev) {

                $('.'+options.pinclass).remove();

                i = i + 10;
                var $img = $(thisObj);
                var offset = $img.offset();
                var x = ev.pageX - offset.left;
                var y = ev.pageY - offset.top;

                var xval = (x - options.xoffset);
                var yval = (y - options.yoffset);
                var imgC = $('<img class="pin '+options.pinclass+'">');
                imgC.css('top', yval+'px');
                imgC.css('left', xval+'px');
                imgC.css('z-index', i);

                imgC.attr('src',  options.pin);

                imgC.appendTo(thisObj);
                $(options.hiddenXid).val(xval);
                $(options.hiddenYid).val(yval);

                // add hidden fields - can use these to save to database
                var hiddenCtl= $('<input type="hidden" name="hiddenpin" class="pin '+options.pinclass+'">');
                hiddenCtl.css('top', y);
                hiddenCtl.css('left', x);
                hiddenCtl.val(x + "#" + y);
                hiddenCtl.appendTo(thisObj);

            });

        },
        dropMulti: function(options) {

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var thisObj = this;

            thisObj.css({'cursor' : options.cursor, 'background-color' : options.backgroundColor , 'background-image' : "url('"+options.backgroundImage+"')",'height' : options.fixedHeight , 'width' : options.fixedWidth});
            var i = 10;
            thisObj.on(options.userevent, function (ev) {

                i = i + 10;
                var $img = $(thisObj);
                var offset = $img.offset();
                var x = ev.pageX - offset.left;
                var y = ev.pageY - offset.top;

                var xval = (x - options.xoffset);
                var yval = (y - options.yoffset);
                var imgC = $('<img class="pin">');
                imgC.css('top', yval+'px');
                imgC.css('left', xval+'px');
                imgC.css('z-index', i);

                imgC.attr('src',  options.pin);

                imgC.appendTo(thisObj);
                // console.log(ev.target);
                $(options.hiddenXid).val(xval);
                $(options.hiddenYid).val(yval);

                // add hidden fields - can use these to save to database
                var hiddenCtl= $('<input type="hidden" name="hiddenpin" class="pin">');
                hiddenCtl.css('top', y);
                hiddenCtl.css('left', x);
                hiddenCtl.val(x + "#" + y);
                hiddenCtl.appendTo(thisObj);

            });

        },
        showPin: function(options) {

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            this.css({'cursor' : options.cursor, 'background-color' : options.backgroundColor , 'background-image' : "url('"+options.backgroundImage+"')",'height' : options.fixedHeight , 'width' : options.fixedWidth});

            var xval = (options.pinX);
            var yval = (options.pinY);
            var imgC = $('<img class="pin">');
            imgC.css('top', yval+'px');
            imgC.css('left', xval+'px');

            imgC.attr('src',  options.pin);

            imgC.appendTo(this);
            $(options.hiddenXid).val(xval);
            $(options.hiddenYid).val(yval);

        },
        showPins: function(options) {

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            this.css({'cursor' : options.cursor, 'background-color' : options.backgroundColor , 'background-image' : "url('"+options.backgroundImage+"')",'height' : options.fixedHeight , 'width' : options.fixedWidth});

            for(var i=0; i < (options.pinDataSet).markers.length; i++)
            {
                var dataPin = options.pinDataSet.markers[i];

                var imgC = $('<img rel="/map-content.php?id='+dataPin.id+'" class="pin '+options.pinclass+'" style="top:'+dataPin.ycoord+'px;left:'+dataPin.xcoord+'px;">');
                imgC.attr('src',  options.pin);
                imgC.attr('title',  dataPin.title);
                imgC.appendTo(this);
            }
        }
    };
    if (methods[method]) {

        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {

        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);

    } else {

        alert("method does not exist");
    }
}
})( jQuery );
```

---

I've downloaded this code in google. This code drops a marker to the image. But how can i save the marker that i've drop to the mysql database with the codes given above? what codes to be added or to be modified? so that the markers will be save to the database. and what are the table entities to be used to insert the marker data to the database?